# Less syntax error in Twitter Boostrap - mixins.less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am getting syntax errors on the section below and I'm not sure syntactically what the issue is:

```
.spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
    (~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
    .spanX(@index - 1);
}
.spanX (0) {}
```

Comment: What version of less and what tool are you using to compile? This was only introduced into less.js/dotless in 1.3.0

Comment: @Luke - using an array of tools ;-) I use Cassette (v2 beta as off today's repo - which uses dotless) and also use Mindscape's workbench tool within Visual Studio which provides less support. Running the latest of all. Eventually had to revert to an older version of mixins.less to get it working.

Comment: the latest 2.0.3 bootstrap compiles fine with dotless 1.3.X so I'm a bit confused as to what is causing the problem. The cassette author has been in touch before and should be using an up-to-date dll.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to cassette v 2 (beta) and all OK